# Existence of Injective function

Tags: real-analysis

Can a injective map $f$ be defined from  $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $(0,1)^w$ where $w$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$, without using the choice axiom?
Literally, I am not getting any clue. So, I would like to have detailed explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Latex would help all of us and is part of the guideline of this site. Apart from that, what is $(0,1)$? The open interval of the reals?

Comment: Do you mean $\{0, 1\}$, the set of two objects, or $(0, 1)$, the open interval?

Comment: I meant open interval (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, for any $n \geq 0$, there exists a unique sequence $(y_n) \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ such that $n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^ky_k$. Now, for $n \geq 0$, let $f(n) = (y_0,y_1,y_2,$...$)$.

In the case that you were talking about $(0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ rather than $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, simply define $f(n) = (\frac{1}{n+2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},$...$)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $\{0,1\}^\omega,$ define $f(n)$ to be the sequence having $1$ in the $n$th slot and $0$'s elsewhere. For the case of $(0,1)^\omega,$ define $f(n)$ to be the sequence having $2/3$ in the $n$th slot and $1/3$'s elsewhere. No AC needed.